# Getting Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Tags: angular10, angular-upgrade, angular-ivy

Have recently upgraded my angular project from version 9 to version 10, and have enabled IVY, after enabling IVY getting lot of  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration errors.
Below errors are during npm run build:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/G03jS.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KlMw.png)

Getting the above error for most of the components used in my project. I am getting this error when I do npm run build, when I do ng serve I am getting Module not found errors
Below errors are during ng serve:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJd6s.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNBsa.png)

Please do help.

Got this error during Angular upgradation from Angular version 9 to Angular version 10